# Convert Selected Combobox item to a decimal and store it in the database

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My problem:
I have a Combobox, with the values of : 11,251,351,451 and 551.
I am using the MVVM pattern in WPF, and I want to use a converter, to convert the selected value to a decimal and save it to the database using the binding.

As soon as I try to convert the value, I get the following exception on my ConvertBack Method in my Converter.

Here is the code for my Converter:

```
        {
            try
            {
                string str_value = value.ToString();
                decimal decimal_myvalue = decimal.Parse(str_value);
                return decimal_myvalue;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                var a = e.Message;
            }
            return 0;
            
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

here is my xaml code for my combobox:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Transaction.PoisonSeeds, Converter={StaticResource PoisonSeedValueConverter}}" ...>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="11"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="251"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="351"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="451"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="551"/>
</ComboBox>
```

is there anything noticable that I am doing wrong?

what can another solution be?

Comment: "I am using the MVVM pattern in WPF" - where is it? I don't see it around

Comment: Set `SelectedValuePath="Content"` (and read the ItemsControl documentation to understand how SelectedValue works). Besides that, it might be a lot simpler (and more MVVM) to bind the ItemsSource to a collection of decimals, and then just bind SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue.

Comment: I am not calling the Convertback Method. It does not even step into the Convert Method

Comment: Will try it thanks clemens

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ConvertBack` method instead of the `Convert`, since you are writing to the Source

In `Convert` you should go from decimal to string.

In `'ConvertBack'` you should convert from string to decimal

And as @Clements has pointed out: add SelectedValuePath="Content"

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you throw exception in convert back... but going beyond that, there are a lot problems ahead. Let me explain...

It would be enough to place breakpoint in `ConvertBack` method of the converter to see that value to be converted is `ComboBoxItem` - not something you'd expect.

Alternatively, look in the output window (if you use Visual Studio), where you also get some information what happens "inside" the app:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: 11' from type 'ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.Decimal' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: DecimalConverter cannot convert from System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
```

So, instead of defining combobx items, you should bind to collection in your view model, which will holsd decimals - then you just bind to selected item, no need to convert anything.

So you have to options:

1. Dirty - in your converter, modify code so it handles `ComboboxItem` instead of a plain string (as I can assume from your code).
2. Clean MVVM way (suggested by @Clemens):
   define on your view model items source

```
public ObservableCollection<decimal> CbxItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<decimal>();
```

and in XAML you bind to it:

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding CbxItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyDecimal}" />
```